# How do I add different data in my new chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have made my bar-chart to a line-chart with a init and destroy function but I would like to add different data and labels in the new chart, so the line-chart contains labels like "palm oil", "sunflower oil", "olive oil" etc. but the bar-chart keeps the original data . How do I do this? When I add data to the init function, the whole chart just disappears.

```
    <script> 
            var canvas = document.getElementById("barChart");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // We are only changing the chart type, so let's make that a global variable along with the chart object:
    var chartType = 'bar';
    var myBarChart;

    // Global Options:
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'grey';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16;

    var data = {
      labels: [ "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017",],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Miljoner ton",
        fill: true,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,0.4)",
        borderColor: "green", // The main line color
        borderCapStyle: 'square',
        pointBorderColor: "white",
        pointBackgroundColor: "green",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 8,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "yellow",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "green",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 4,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        data: [56.38, 59.3, 61.81, 58.83, 52.32, 66.86],
        spanGaps: true,
      }]
    };

    // Notice the scaleLabel at the same level as Ticks
    var options = {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      },
      title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        display: true,
        text: 'Källa: Globallife.org',
        position: 'bottom'
      }
    };

    //Lägg till data            
function addData() {
  myBarChart.data.labels[6] ="Ekologisk palmolja";

  myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data[6] = 14;

  myBarChart.update();

}

    // We add an init function down here after the chart options are declared.

    init();

    function init() {
      // Chart declaration:
      myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: chartType,
        data: data,
        options: options
      });
    }



    function button() {
      //destroy chart:
      myBarChart.destroy();
      //change chart type: 
      this.chartType = (this.chartType == 'bar') ? 'line' : 'bar';


      //restart chart:
      init();
    }


                // requested function; removes index 7.
function removeData(e) {
  myBarChart.data.labels.splice(7, 1);
  myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data.splice(7, 1);
  myBarChart.update();

}

                function removeData(e) {
  myBarChart.data.labels.splice(6, 1);
  myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data.splice(6, 1);
  myBarChart.update();
}

                document.getElementById('remove1').addEventListener('click', removeData);
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is supplying the same `data` variable each time you create a chart. Below is an example of switching between two completely different charts by providing different configuration options to the Chart constructor.

```js
let lineConfig = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y'],
      datasets: [{
        data: [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
      }]
    }
  },
  barConfig = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
      datasets: [{
        data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
      }]
    }
  },
  activeType = 'bar', // we'll start with a bar chart.
  myChart;

function init(config) {
  // create a new chart with the supplied config.
  myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), config);
}

// first init as a bar chart.
init(barConfig);

document.getElementById('switch').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // every time the button is clicked we destroy the existing chart.
  myChart.destroy();
  if (activeType == 'bar') {
    // chart was a bar, init a new line chart.
    activeType = 'line';
    init(lineConfig);
    return;
  }

  // chart was a line, init a new bar chart.
  activeType = 'bar';
  init(barConfig);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
<button id="switch">Switch</button>
```